# ASP.NET Core web application running slow & occasionally timing out while running large queries to database after updating to .NET 8

Tags: iis, sql-server-2012, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2022, .net-8.0

I recently updated my ASP.NET Core MVC web application from .NET 5 to .NET 8 and have since been having intermittent timeout issues with IIS while running larger queries against the database.

The application starts fine, lets me log in, and lets me view most pages, but any page with a table that is pulling a larger list of data back eventually times out. The rest of the application will continue to work, but it is much slower than it was before I updated everything.

I had to upgrade from Visual Studio Community 2019 to 2022 (v17.9.4) to use .NET 8. And I also updated SQL Server Management Studio to 2019 (v19.3). Microsoft SQL Server is still 2012 (v11.0.2100) though.

The only error occurring while running the web application is this IIS timeout error:

> Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

I can run the queries that are triggering this timeout in SSMS, and they run pretty quickly (the largest query takes 8 seconds in SSMS). They were not giving timeout errors prior to updating to .NET 8 and Visual Studio 2022.

When I run my other ASP.NET Core console application that I also updated from .NET 5 to .NET 8, I get this TLS Security Warning:

> Security Warning: The negotiated TLS 1.0 is an insecure protocol and is supported for backward compatibility only. The recommended protocol version is TLS 1.2 and later.

That security warning message pops up on the command prompt every time the database connection is being opened.

Would that TLS security warning be the reason I’m getting a timeout error? And if so, what solutions can I take to remove that warning? (For example, would upgrading Microsoft SQL Server to the latest version remove this warning and stop the timeout errors?) I tried updating SSMS to 2019, but that did not solve the TLS warning or the timeout problem.

I also only have 13 GB of storage free on the C: drive (and 32 GB free on the D: drive). Would the lower amount of space left on the C: drive have anything to do with the timeout error? The timeouts are happening both while debugging the application and when I run the program through the browser after publishing to another folder. When I restart the server, everything seems to work quickly like it used to, but after only 15 minutes or so, the application slows down and the timeouts start.

Any advice on what to try from here would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

I tried clearing out space on the C: drive: I used the Disk Clean up, cleared the nuget cache, removed temp files. Then I restarted the server. I could only get 13 GB space free on the C: drive.

I updated SQL Server Management Studio to v19. This did not remove the TLS security warning.

I'm not sure if I'm having a server space issue or a Microsoft SQL Server issue.

Comment: This could be a "runs slow in the app and fast in SSMS" situation. which means there is a database performance issue that you can't recreate in SSMS. Maybe have a read of this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/database-engine/performance/troubleshoot-application-slow-ssms-fast  which is a friendlier explanation of this https://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html

Comment: 1) There are 3 years of changes from .NET 5 to .NET 8, so such issues are expected. 2) Running big queries (or similar things) in a single request is a red flag for web apps and usually requires design changes. Ideally all requests/responses should be designed to take a fixed amount of time (and as short as possible). So a state machine should be used for browser side to see if data queries finish (pull model) or a bi-directional channel (like SignalR) to allow the server to notify browsers. 3) The TLS issue should be a separate topic.

Comment: This will be a long time query issue, we need to use other way to increase the query time and your application codes to increase the execute time avoid timeout.

Comment: Thank you all for that feedback. That helped me narrow it down that it’s likely not a problem with the TLS warning. I’m going to try out the suggestions from the links provided by @Nick.Mc to see if the query is more labor-intensive than I think.

As an additional note though, the query does not seem to have an issue on the production server which has much more free space on it than the development server. I’m going to also try to clear more space on the C: Drive to see if that helps as well.

I’ll come back and update this question if I find anything that works. Thank you again!

Comment: The fact that it runs fine is also a symptom of "runs slow in the app fast in SSMS". Do you have a DBA? They should be able to confirm whether it's the query and whether it is a parameter sniffing / bad plan issue

Comment: After further sleuthing, I found that when I run Visual Studio 2022, the CPU and Memory in the task manager both jump up to 98%-100%, which seems to be causing the problem.

I’m getting more space on the C: Drive to ensure Visual Studio has enough memory to operate correctly. Then, if I still have an issue, I will further check out the queries to see if they are the culprit to the application running slow. Thank you all for your help!